# How to delete all nodes of given root in sql adjacency list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

Having this table:

[image]

I want to delete the root node, by sending a query ID=1
and I want that all the subnodes of this id will be deleted as well.

how can I do it?

Comment: So, if you delete `id = 1`  the three records need to be deleted? Could you show more records from the table?

Comment: @gotqn Yes, that's true. there isn't more, that's a table example. you could have more records like Id 4 Name 2 Owner 2 Parent NULL etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a recursive common table expression.

To get all children of one node you can use:

```
with tree as (
  select id, parent
  from eyalewin
  where id = 1
  union all
  select c.id, c.parent
  from eyalewin c
    join tree p on p.id = c.parent
)
select *
from tree;
```

This can then be used to delete all of them:

```
with tree as (
  select id, parent
  from eyalewin
  where id = 1
  union all
  select c.id, c.parent
  from eyalewin c
    join tree p on p.id = c.parent
)
delete from eyalewin
where id in (select id 
             from tree);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following data:

[image]

and you want to delete record `2.1` and all of his descendants (in this case `2.1.3` only). You can use the following code to get the `IDs` that needs to be deleted:

```
WITH DataSource ([ID], [HierarchyLevel]) AS
(
    SELECT [ID]
          ,CAST(REPLACE('/' + [Name] + '/', '.', '/') AS HIERARCHYID)
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT [ID]
      ,[HierarchyLevel].ToString()
FROM DataSource
WHERE [HierarchyLevel].IsDescendantOf('/2/1/') = 1;
```

[image]

Basically, we convert your record to `hierarchy id` type and use the build-in [IsDescendantOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677203.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function to get all `childs` of the node.

This is full working example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Owner] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Parent] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [Name], [Owner], [Parent])
VALUES (1, '1', '1', NULL)
      ,(2, '1.1', '1.1', 1)
      ,(3, '1.1.1', '1.1.1', 2)
      ,(4, '2', '2.1', NULL)
      ,(5, '2.1', '2.1', 4)
      ,(6, '2.2', '2.2', 4)
      ,(7, '2.1.3', '2.1.3', 5);


WITH DataSource ([ID], [HierarchyLevel]) AS
(
    SELECT [ID]
          ,CAST(REPLACE('/' + [Name] + '/', '.', '/') AS HIERARCHYID)
    FROM @DataSource
)
DELETE @DataSource
FROM @DataSource DS
INNER JOIN DataSource DS1
    ON DS.[ID] = DS1.[ID]
WHERE [HierarchyLevel].IsDescendantOf('/2/1/') = 1;

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource;
```